# How to write a object into a file in java?

Tags: java, c

I want to convert the following c code to java. I did that somehow but, after writing to the files I compared both of the content in beyond compare and there is a lot of different.
Please suggest me how to write the same as c in java

C code:

```
const struct bin_header bin_header = {
 .magic = "VVN",
 .header_size = 0x10,
 .version = (0x01 << 24) | 0x010000,
 .core = (0x02 << 24) | 0x000501,
};
FILE* ofp = fopen(outfilename, "wb");
fwrite(&bin_header, sizeof(bin_header), 1, ofp)
```

Java code:

```
/* class because there is no struct in java */ 
class bin_header implements Serializable      {
    String magic;
    long header_size;
    long version;
    long core;

    bin_header () { 
        magic = "VVN";
        header_size = 0x10;
        version = (0x01 << 24) | 0x010000;
        core = (0x02 << 24) | 0x000501;
      }

  };
```

/* function  for writing */

```
writeByVVN() {
    bin_header bin_header = new bin_header();
    Fout = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(Fout);
    oos.writeObject(bin_header);
}
```

Comment: You are looking for serialization I think, google for it!

Comment: You cannot use `ObjectOutputStream` for that; also you have to know what encoding is used for your string. Use a `DataOutputStream`.

Comment: Also, you are aware that your C code is endianness dependent, right?

Comment: @fge can you expand on why he cannot use an ObjectOutputStream? I was in the process of testing a solution and it seams to work well

Comment: @Aaron because an ObjectOutputStream will include a Java specific header (the value of `serialVersionUID`, or a default one if not specified in your class; whereas the OP tries to write the raw info directly (in an alignment-dependent manner to boot, meh). And of course there's the string problem: serializing strings is highly dependent on the encoding you choose to use. There's .{read,write}UTF(), of course, but no idea how you'd read that back in C.

Comment: The C implementation is environment-dependent. Run the C code, open the created file with hex editor, then write some code in Java to reproduce the data on `byte[]` array using the data on the object.

Comment: @fge ok, I hadn't realized OP wanted an iteroperable file format. Thanks for the info !

Comment: @fge , I tried with `DataOutputStream` for now its better than `ObjectOutputStream` but still it does not  match the same as c. I am suspecting that data sizes are different so that they are not same. Am i correct? Is there any way to make them same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to write the object members to a file with endianness also.
 I used ByteBuffer for it

```
   int write(FileOutputStream fout) throws IOException {
            int bytes;
            FileChannel fChan = fout.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer str = ByteBuffer.wrap(magic.getBytes());
        bytes = fChan.write(str);

        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
        buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

        buf.putInt(header_size);
        buf.rewind();
        bytes  += fChan.write(buf);
        buf.clear();
        ...

        return bytes;
   }

int read(FileInputStream fIn)  throws IOException {
    int bytes = 0;
    FileChannel fChan = fIn.getChannel();

    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

    bytes = fChan.read(buf);
    buf.rewind();
    magic = new String(buf.array());
    buf.clear();

    ...

    return bytes;
}
```